# How can I resolve a consistent-return error is eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've got this eslint error  `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return` and even after reading the [doc](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) I still don't know how to handle it.

```js
/**
 * @param selector
 * @returns {Promise<unknown>}
 */
let waitForElm = function(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
};
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You only have one return in the promise executor, however there are two code branches - one when the `if` executes, one when it doesn't. Also, no `return` in the callback to the MutationObserver. Yet it hardly matters, since neither of these really use the return values.

Answer (score 2):

You pass an arrow function to `new Promise`.

If `document.querySelector(selector)` is true, then you enter an `if` block and there is a `return` statement.

If it isn't true, then you go through the rest of the function and there **isn't** a `return` statement.

So sometimes there is a `return` and sometimes there isn't.

To be constant, there should always be a `return`.

So add one at the end of the function.